# Python - If nothing happens for 1 minute, proceed code

Tags: python, wait

I am writing a script which sends a serial message over a websocket to a device. When I want to start the device I write:

```
def start(ws):
    """
    Function to send the start command
    """
    print("start")
    command = dict()
    command["commandId"] = 601
    command["id"] = 54321
    command["params"] = {}
    send_command(ws, command)
```

Every 5 hours or so the device restarts, during the restart, my function start request does not run and my code stops completely.

My question is, is there a way to tell python: "If nothing has happened for 1 minute, try again"

Comment: What does "nothing happened" mean?  What is going on normally, when the device is not restarting?  Is Python getting stuck in a particular API call, like maybe in the `send_command` call you show in your question?  There is almost certainly a way to have Python do what you want, but it isn't yet clear to me what that is.

Comment: Hi Steve, a robot moves the device, the device runs, then the robot moves again under normal conditions. In this situation, the robot moves, the code reaches start(ws) and then stops forever. It does not print "start" at the top of the function. It perhaps sends the "send_command", but because the device is switched off, does not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what `ws` is or how you set it up; but you want to add a timeout to the socket.

https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.client.connect has a `timeout` keyword; refer to the documentation for details about what it does.

If this is not the websocket library you are using, please update your question with details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sleep` from `time` module

```
import time
time.sleep(60) # waits for 1 minute
```

Also, do consider `Multithreading` for `sleep`

```
import threading 
import time
  
def print_hello():
  for i in range(4):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Hello")
  
def print_hi(): 
    for i in range(4): 
      time.sleep(0.7)
      print("Hi") 

t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)  
t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_hi)  
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

The above program has two threads. Have used time.sleep(0.5) and time.sleep(0.75) to suspend execution of these two threads for 0.5 seconds and 0.7 seconds respectively.

[more here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep)